TensorFlow custom object detection want work in Windows 11 native with GPU support
I recently tried creating a custom object detection model using tensorflow in my Windows 11 local machine using Tensorflow 2.10. But got an error from Tensorflow object detection api model_builder_tf2_test.py.
ImportError: cannot import name 'tensor' from 'tensorflow.python.framework
I referred many articles and papers most required to use TensorFlow version 2.13 to solve this Tensorflow InceptionV4 ImportError: cannot import name 'tensor' from 'tensorflow.python.framework'. It solved the problem but Tensorflow 2.13 do not support GPU accessorization in Windows native. How to do this in Windows 11?
I referred many articles and papers most required to use TensorFlow version 2.13 to solve this Tensorflow InceptionV4 ImportError: cannot import name 'tensor' from 'tensorflow.python.framework'. It solved the problem but Tensorflow 2.13 do not support GPU accessorization in Windows native.
I want to know is there any chance to do this in Windows 11?
